# Customizing ChartJS.org

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is there any chance to customize chartjs with a large amount of data? To be exact, the problem is with overlapping labels when there is more data than in it's documentation. I've worked with other charting systems and labels (represented by dates for examples) where properly scaling, but ChartJS seems to do nothing with that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Chart.Scatter plugin instead the line chart.

http://dima117.github.io/Chart.Scatter/

It receives the array of points with X and Y fields. Scale parameters are calculated automatically based on chart data